# Usage of dabei and wobei

Tags: difference, pronoun

What do the words *wobei* and *dabei* mean? And what is the difference in their usage?

> Sie gab mir das Buch, wobei sie vermied, mich anzusehen.
>   Sie gab mir das Buch, dabei vermied sie, mich anzusehen.

Do they mean *at the same time?*
Which one is formal, *wobei* or *dabei?*

Comment: Which one is formal? Wobei or dabei?

Comment: From grammar, both are correct, the meaning differs. But I think, somebody else is more competent then me to explain the difference. I will take a look for the question. If there is now answer next time, I will try an explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no semantic difference in your example, but consider this one:

> Sie gab mir das Buch, dabei bemerkte sie, dass der Umschlag verdreckt war.

*Wobei* only states that things are happening at the same time, *dabei* can also imply that the second action is a consequence of the first one. Therefore, *dabei* is preferable in this case. Be aware that this is just a weak additional meaning, the main meaning still being “at the same time”.

Both words are equally formal. Colloquially, *wobei* can also be used to state an objection or relativization:

> Man kann hier gut essen, wobei man sagen muss, dass es ein bisschen teuer ist.

**Edit:** As Emanuel pointed out, while Duden claims this is colloquial, it is also used in written language. I changed the example to a better one he gave in the comments.

Comment: In your last paragraph you're stating that the objection-wobei is colloquial and it has to be initial. That is not true IMO... wobei actually USUALLY has this "objection" idea in it and the mere happening at the same time is done by "während"... "Man kann hier gut essen, wobei man sagen muss, dass es ein bisschen teuer ist". THere is no temporal aspect at all in this example. I think you should maybe work that into your answer.

Comment: [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wobei) claims it's colloquial and that's also my experience. It's true that it does not necessarily has to be used initial with this meaning, and in spoken language, this may even be the usual meaning. I can't remember it being used in written language much, but I was unsure, so I looked it up in Duden. *während* is another thing, it describes something that is happening while another action is ongoing, which is slightly different to two things happen at the same time.

Comment: That is surprising with the Duden but oh well, I removed the downvote. Anyway, I would be really interested in an example or an explanation how exactly 2 things happening at the same time and something happening while something else is happening (which is "another action is ongoing) are different.

Comment: Example: „*Der Postbote kam, während ich außer Haus war.*”. You cannot use *wobei* or *dabei* here.

Comment: True. Can you give me an example for a temporal wobei that is not exchangeable for "während", too?

Comment: I cannot think of one. *während* may be applicable to a superset of the situations where *wobei* can be used. But take the one from the question as example: You can use *während* here, but you need to switch the two parts: „*Sie vermied, mich anzusehen, während sie mir das Buch gab.*” So, I'd say, *wobei* can be used when actions are logically linked to each other and places the dominant action first. *während* does only requires a temporal link and places the dominant action last.

Comment: Okay. But my issues with the "colloquial" are back. You can't really say it isn't written: https://www.google.de/search?q=%22wobei+sie%22&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&oq=%22wobei+sie%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3421j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=%22wobei%22+site:zeit.de  It is. I can find you more examples.

Comment: `dabei` can not mean, that the second action happened after the first one, any more than `wobei` does.

Comment: Toscho: Did I claim something else?

Answer (score 9):

Both `dabei` and `wobei` are semantically identical. They only differ in syntax.

- `dabei` is an adverb which can be roughly interchangeably used to `während` and thus can but need not start main clauses.
- `wobei` is a relative pronomial adverb and thus always starts subclauses.

Consequently, your first proposal is grammatically correct whereas your second proposal has a slight grammatical error: The two sentences `Sie gab mir das Buch.` and `Dabei vermied sie(,) mich anzusehen.` are syntactically not connected. `Dabei` refers to `Sie gab mir das Buch.` but only semantically. Syntactically, it's a fully autonomous adverb in the second sentence. So, if you want to connect these two sentences into one, you should use a semicolon instead of a comma:

> Sie gab mir das Buch; dabei vermied sie(,) mich anzusehen.

But you can and for the sake of simplicity should keep both sentences separate:

> Sie gab mir das Buch. Dabei vermied sie(,) mich anzusehen.

Comment: +1 for the the semicolon and for the optional comma.